# How to set the default version of PHP on openSUSE 12.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, opensuse

Note: I'm so new to this OS just 2 weeks ago. Hope someone can help me.

I have 2 php version, php5 and php7. I want to know how to set the default php to php7 so that I can proceed to the next step of installing "Laravel framework".

When I open a terminal and type the command `php --version` the result is

> PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2016 19:17:59) ( NTS )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group

but when I try to `phpinfo()`; the result is PHP Version 5.3.15

How can I set it to php7 or how can I switch to other version to another?

Comment: What you really want to know is how to configure your web server to run a specific version of php, but you didn't mention which web server you are using.

Comment: I got it from the repository of opensuse 12,2 LAMP. Im using Apache2 web server sir.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a supported release of openSUSE. It will come with a more recent version of PHP.

[openSUSE 12.2 was released in March 2011, and reached end of life in May 2013.](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:12.1)

Comment: so the only option is to upgrade or change my current OS that has a support of php 5.5 up.

Comment: It's not the *only* option, but it is the best option. Running an OS that stopped receiving updates (including security updates) three years ago is a bad idea in general, especially if you plan on using it as a web server.

Comment: ahh ok Sir.. I will open up to my superior sir what you have told here so that we can propose to our head that we will not using openSUSE 12.2, instead we will use other OS that still have a support.. Your a great help sir. thnks.